# Having trouble with specific function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question concerning javascript. I have created a function which prompts the user to enter a string, and once the string is entered will perform a for loop to go through the entire length of the string, looking for the character "B" and then return the number of "B"s found in the result variable. As far as my knowledge, I feel that the code I have should work, however not matter how many "B" are present within my code, the function consistently returns 2. Any ideas on why this would be happening

```
function countBs(string) {
    var result = 1;
    var string = prompt("Please Enter a String");
    for (count = 0; count < string.length; string++) {
        if (string.charAt(count) == "B") {
            result += 1;
            return result;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Should be `count++` not `string++`

Comment: you're returning in the `for`, not at the end of the function.

Comment: Also, you need to change result to 0, not 1.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have:

```
function countBs(string) {
var result = 1;
var string = prompt("Please Enter a String");
for (count = 0; count < string.length; string++) {
    if (string.charAt(count) == "B") {
            result += 1;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

which should be:

```
function countBs(string) {
    var result = 0;
    var string = prompt("Please Enter a String");
    for (count = 0; count < string.length; count++) {
        if (string.charAt(count) == "B") {
            result += 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

(notice the count++, the change from 0->1 for result, and the moved return)

Comment: ... except it will still return when it hits the first "B".

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
function countBs(string) {
    var result = 0;
    var string = string || prompt("Please Enter a String");
    for (var count = 0; count < string.length; ++count)
        if (string.charAt(count) == "B")
            result += 1;
    return result;
};
```

Make sure it's "var count" and not just "count" or you will pollute the global sapce.

There are other ways as well:

```
"BBBBBB".split('B').length-1
```

and

```
("BBBBBBB".match(/B/g)||"").length
```

or case insensitive

```
("BbBbBbB".match(/B/gi)||"").length
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change string in the for loop to count

```
function countBs(string) {
    var result = 1;
    var string = prompt("Please Enter a String");
    for (count = 0; count < string.length; count++) {
        if (string.charAt(count) == "B") {
            result += 1;

        }
    }
 return result;
};
```

Comment: `result` should be 0, not 1, and `count` should have `var ` before it.  Also the string passed in will never be checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function countBs() {                                      // no parameter
    var string = prompt("Please Enter a String");         // provide string
    return string.split('').reduce(function (x, letter) { // string became array and array can use build in method reduce
        return letter === 'B' ? x + 1 : x;                // test for B and return increment, otherwise old count
    }, 0);                                                // start with count 0
};
```

take the string and make a real array, and then iterate over all letters and count the Bs